# How are the design variables in the SimpleGA or DifferentialEvolution drivers initialized?

Tags: openmdao

I am having trouble navigating the source code to see how the design variables in the initial population for the SimpleGA and DifferentialEvolution Drivers are set.  Is there some sort of Latin Hypercube sampling of the design variable ranges?  Do the initial values I set in my problem instance get used like they would for the other drivers (Scipy and pyOptSparse)?

Many thanks,
Garrett

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For these two drivers, the initial value in the model is not used. Its not even clear to me what it would mean to use that value directly, since you need a stochastically generated population --- but I'm admittedly not an expert on the latest GA population initialization methods. However, I can answer the question of how they do get initialized as of OpenMDAO V3.17:

[Simple GA Driver:](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/blob/9a5228a963fb85b74926f33e51f8663d768de086/openmdao/drivers/genetic_algorithm_driver.py#L651-L653)

This driver does seem to use an LHS sampling like this:

```
new_gen = np.round(lhs(self.lchrom, self.npop, criterion='center',
                           random_state=random_state))
new_gen[0] = self.encode(x0, vlb, vub, bits)
```

[Differential Evolution Driver:](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/blob/9a5228a963fb85b74926f33e51f8663d768de086/openmdao/drivers/differential_evolution_driver.py#L544-L545)
This driver uses a uniform random distribution like this:

```
population = rng.random([self.npop, self.lchrom]) * (vub - vlb) + vlb  # scale to bounds
```

Admittedly, it doesn't make a whole lot of sense why the intialization methods are different, and perhaps there should be some option to pick from a set of methods or provide your own initial population somehow. A [POEM](https://github.com/openmdao/poems) and/or pull-request to improve this would be most welcome.

Comment: Thank you, Justin.  I agree that aligning the two would be helpful.  Am I correct in reading that the Simple GA driver uses the LHS values for npop-1 entries and the user-provided x0 for the first entry?  That is actually the behavior I was hoping for.

Comment: yes, correct. Strictly speaking that means that the LHS sample is not complete either (since that initial population member is now different). If you really wanted this behavior the more correct manner might be to do n_pop - 1 samples for the LHS.